# How do I install Waterfox?

Tags: software-installation, firefox, browser

The [Waterfox](https://www.waterfoxproject.org/) web browser is a 64-bit-only open source project based on Firefox.

I would like to see how is the performance compared to Firefox, apparently its better.

Being new to Linux, it's a challenge when it comes to packages that are not .deb. On the official site, Waterfox [is provided](https://www.waterfoxproject.org/downloads) as a `.tar.bz2` file. How can I install Waterfox on Lubuntu 17.04 and also add an entry for it in my menu, under Internet, alongside Firefox?

Comment: extract the archive. there should be a readme file inside. what you need to do depends on what is in the archive.

Comment: This should not have been closed. There is a way to install Waterfox using apt, but there is no way to leave an answer.

Comment: The OP expressed concern about installing from tarball, probably because he thought that was the only way to do it, but there is in fact a repository that he could use.

Answer (score 15):

There is [an unofficial repository](https://github.com/hawkeye116477/waterfox-deb) from which [you can download and install](https://software.opensuse.org//download.html?project=home%3Ahawkeye116477%3Awaterfox&package=waterfox) Waterfox using `apt`.

1. Add the repository to your sources:

   ```
   sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/hawkeye116477:/waterfox/xUbuntu_Next/ /' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:hawkeye116477:waterfox.list"
   ```
2. Add the public key:

   `wget -nv https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:hawkeye116477:waterfox/xUbuntu_Next/Release.key -O Release.key
   sudo apt-key add - < Release.key`

Replace `xUbuntu_Next` with `xUbuntu_19.04` or whichever version as needed.

3. Now update packages and install:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install waterfox
   ```

   If you have problems, you may need to install some dependencies because the developers used the latest version of the GNU Standard C++ Lib, which isn't available on some systems. (I had to do this manually in 14.04. YMMV.)

   Possible step:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libgcc1 libstdc++6
   ```
4. Run `waterfox` at the prompt. Voila!

Comment: The repository was recently changed; I change the URLs involved to reflect this.

Comment: I've updated this once again to reflect current state of the repository and instructions.

Comment: Ok, some formatting issues appeared; I tried to fix them.

Comment: Is this still the way to go? When I start waterfox now I get a notification that my version is out of date and could not be updated by waterfox itself.

Comment: This worked fine on Ubuntu 19.10 too

Comment: I ended up getting a strange error saying (among other things): `waterfox-current-kde : Depends: kwaterfoxhelper but it is not installable ... E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.` It was fixed when I used `aptitude` to install it, like so: https://askubuntu.com/a/451078/419483

Answer (score 10):

```
tar -xvjf ./waterfox.tar.bz2 
cd ./waterfox
./waterfox
```

Using this method Waterfox is running now and it imports all of the settings from Firefox, Great!

Will do some benchmarks later to see how it compares to FF although it feels faster.

Now to figure out how to add shortcuts to the Lubuntu menu...

Comment: I usually launch applications like `. waterfox` which doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: `bash: ./waterfox: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

Answer (score 9):

Download the file, extract using the gui, and link it to the menu.

Unzip and run

1. Download the latest Linux version of the file from [the Waterfox website](https://www.waterfox.net/releases/).
2. Open Caja or another file manager to the folder where the file was downloaded to
3. Double-click the file to open the file in a archive manager
   For example Ubuntu Mate has Grampmpa
4. Extract the folder `Waterfox` to a location in your home folder. You could create a new folder in `~/` called `Programs` to put this kind of software in or put it under the `/home/username` folder.
5. Open the folder in a file manager and double-click **Waterfox** to run the browser and test that it works.

#### Create a link to the Internet menu

1. Open a terminal window
2. Edit the new waterfox.desktop file and add the configuration lines for Waterfox

   To open an edit session in vi:

   ```
   sudo vi /usr/share/applications/waterfox.desktop
   ```

   Content to add to the file:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name='Waterfox'
   Exec='/home/username/waterfox/waterfox'
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   Categories=Network;WebBrowser;Internet
   Icon=/home/username/waterfox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default48.png
   ```

   Use `:wq` to save and exit vi.
   Use `:wq!` if you opened vi without `sudo` and need to force exit.

Check that the Exec points to the Waterfox executable. This assumes it was unzipped in the user's home folder. Use the `ls` command to find and check that the Exec and Icon paths are correct. Refer to the existing Firefox .desktop file for an example.

Have a look at the existing shortcut files, and in particular the one for Firefox to see what the syntax looks like: `ls /usr/share/applications/firefox` then `cat /usr/share/applications/firefox-esr.desktop`

You could copy the an existing entry to tailor to make a new one for Waterfox. Delete the lines that are not needed and edit the lines from Firefox to make Waterfox: `sudo cp /usr/share/applications/firefox-esr.desktop cat /usr/share/applications/waterfox.desktop`

Comment: The update feature is broken and we have to manually download new updates :(

Comment: Best answer of all

Answer (score 1):

copied the existing firefox file, [Desktop Entry]
/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop to waterfox.desktop
(requires sudo -s)

altered the content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Waterfox Web Browser
Comment=Browse the World Wide Web
GenericName=Web Browser
Keywords=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web;Explorer
Exec=waterfox %u
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=waterfox
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/xml;application/rss+xml;application/rdf+xml;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/png;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp;x-scheme-handler/chrome;video/webm;application/x-xpinstall;
StartupNotify=true
Actions=new-window;new-private-window;

[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=Open a New Window
Exec=waterfox -new-window

[Desktop Action new-private-window]
Name=Open a New Private Window
Exec=waterfox -private-window
```

I installed waterfox to /opt/waterfox
and created a link /usr/local/bin  waterfox -> /opt/waterfox/waterfox
as   `ln -s /opt/waterfox/waterfox waterfox`

This works on my system and the icon showed up under Applications

Answer (score 0):

First download the waterfox .tar file from https://www.waterfox.net/download/.

Then move it to a secured folder from the downloads folder. Then extract it there.

Search in the app menu if you can find a "Main menu" software.

If you find it, then click on it and click on "internet". Then click on "New item". Then set a name for the app (for example, Waterfox).

Then click on the icon which will take you to your file system. Then go to the folder in which you have kept the extracted waterfox file. Then from there you will go to,

**Waterfox > browser > chrome > icon > defaults > default128.png**

The icon will be selected.

Then click on browse beside the option command. It will take you again to your file system. Go to the folder in which you have kept the extracted waterfox file. From there you will go to Waterfox and scroll down and you will find a file named waterfox which is a shared library (application/x-sharedlib) type file. Then click on it. Then you will be again on the main page of "Main menu" . Now select "ok". And then go to your menu and search for waterfox. Then you can add it to your desktop by a left click of mouse on the app and then select pin to desktop.

If you do not find "Main menu" named app then you will have to install it.

This procedure was recently tested in Ubuntu MATE 20.04. So hopefully it will work.