# No obvious way to install Waterfox .tar.bz2 update

Tags: updates, browser

In order to update Waterfox, I need to download and install the .tar.bz2 update. However, when I extract the Waterfox folder, there is no install file, readme file or obvious executable that I can use to complete the update. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps this might be useful: https://askubuntu.com/q/935466/57576

Comment: Usually when there is no README or INSTALL file, wherever you got the file will provide instructions (unless you downloaded it from an unofficial source that just mirrored the download tarball only).  The files themselves maybe a clue, did you `file *` to look at what type of files were in the tarball?

Comment: I had a look at that link above, but it's for an unofficial repository, which I won't be doing. None of the other information was useful. The update file is located here: https://www.waterfox.net/download/. There is no installation information. I've checked inside it (before extracting) and there's nothing that resembles a readme, installation or executable file.

Comment: Do you use waterfox classic or waterfox current? I wrote a script to automatically download and install the latest version of waterfox classic if you would like me to post it.