# How to install waterfox from tar.bz2

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, lubuntu, tar

brand new to Lubuntu, as in day 2...trying to install Waterfox. I downloaded tar file (waterfox-G4.1.0.en-US.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2), extracted to a folder, but when I try to click on extracted files 'waterfox' or 'waterfox-bin' to launch, it takes me to an "open with" screen.  Does not work when trying to launch in Terminal either. There is so much stuff to sift through, I can't find a straightforward way to install this. Any help, as simple as possible, would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps some assistance here: https://askubuntu.com/q/935466/57576

Answer (score 0):

1. Press Ctrl-Alt-T to open terminal program (or open Terminal by other way).
2. Type the following commands:

```
sudo apt install wget
cd ~
wget https://github.com/WaterfoxCo/Waterfox/releases/download/G4.1.0/waterfox-G4.1.0.en-US.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
tar -xf waterfox-G4.1.0.en-US.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 # unpack archive
cd waterfox/
./waterfox # or ./waterfox-bin to launch
```