# How to use an older version of firefox in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: firefox

In order to use an older version of firefox I followed the suggestion presented [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505895/how-can-i-install-an-older-version-of-firefox-in-ubuntu-14-04). However, after I have unpacked firefox, started is as another user, added an extension and restarted it, its version 58 again. I want to be able to start version 56 instead (before the Quantum update).

```
$ ls
firefox  firefox-56.0b9.tar
$ cd firefox/
$ ./firefox --no-remote -P firefox56
```

start 58 version of firefox. What is going on?

I need to start the 56 version of firefox with the ability to have extensions working for firefox version 56...

Comment: How do you run firefox 58 as the latest update is 57 ?